# Aparece Fakepath en el navegador al intentar subir un archivo en Angular

Tags: angular, .net, imagen, rutas

Tengo una API en .Net que recibe el path de una imagen y con ello copia esa imagen a otra carpeta destinada al servidor. Por lo tanto en Angular creo un componente que tiene un input para subir una imagen y un carousel que las muestra, pero al capturar la ruta o path de la imagen, para pasarla a mi API, en la consola me muestra "C:\fakepath\{nombrearchivo.jpg}" por ejemplo. Por lo tanto, como esa ruta es falsa, no puedo pasarla a mi API. De hecho estoy probando primero subiendo imágenes en Angular y con una lista local, o sea, estoy probando todo en el front primero, ni siquiera envío a la API aún, y lo único que hace es mostrarme un cuadro nuevo en el carousel pero con la imagen invisible, porque el path es ficticio y por lo tanto no muestra ninguna imagen.

Me he cansado de buscar una solucion a esto y todos dicen que es por temas de seguridad y no se qué, pero nadie da una solución. Necesito pasar el path a mi API, de lo contrario no puede hacer la copia de la imagen. Por favor, les suplico una solución, hace semanas que estoy con este problema.

IMAGE-FORM.HTML

```
<div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <form [formGroup]="imageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <input  type="file"
                 name="image_chooser"
                 id="image_chooser" 
                 accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
                 formControlName="imageFile">
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-11">
                <label for="image_description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 name="image_description" 
                 id="image_desctription" 
                 formControlName="description">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>   


        <div class="row align-item-center">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

IMAGE-FORM.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ImagesService } from 'src/app/services/images.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-form',
  templateUrl: './image-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-form.component.css']
})
export class ImageFormComponent implements OnInit {

  imageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    imageFile: [],
    description: ['']
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private imageService:ImagesService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


  onSubmit(event:Event):void{
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.imageForm.value['imageFile']);

    this.imageService.saveImage(this.imageForm.value);
  }
}
```

IMAGE-SERVICE.TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IMAGES } from 'src/fake_data/FakeImages';
import { Image } from 'src/interfaces/IImage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImagesService {

  private _fakeImages:Image[] = IMAGES;

  constructor() { }

  getImages(){
    return this._fakeImages;
  }

  saveImage(newImage:any):void{
    console.log(newImage);
    const image:Image = {
      ImageId: 0,
      Name: "",
      Extension: "jpg",
      Description: newImage.description,
      Path: newImage.imageFile
    }
    console.log(image);
    this._fakeImages.push(image);
  }

}
```

Frontend repo: https://github.com/diegorus92/Frontend-ImageCollection/tree/develop
por si acaso Backend repo: https://github.com/diegorus92/Backend-ImageCollection/tree/develop

Ojalá puedan ayudarme. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Pero es que no.. el navegador no te va a decir la ruta real del archivo, y menos al back.. porque deberias saber de donde saque mi archivo? que es lo que estas buscando?? porque necesitas la ruta, si el archivo va por internet y la ruta ya no importa?

Comment: Si la ruta de la imagen está en tu máquina local, ¿de qué sirve que le envíes esa ruta a la API si no podrá accederla? Lo que tienes que hacer es implementar una carga de archivos y transferir el contenido del archivo, no su ruta local. Luego que el backend haya guardado el archivo debe devolver la url para accederlo y esa url es la que se usa en el front.

Comment: Muchas gracias gente . SI lo estaba probando de forma local. Ahora entiendo que la forma que dice @Lobos era la correcta. Saludos